# Confusion about super keyword; Decorator Pattern implemented in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, super

the above explanation is very nice.

However, I am slightly confused by the implementation of Decorator Pattern (DeP) as given in

http://www.netobjectives.com/resources/books/design-patterns-explained/java-code-examples/chapter17/#17-1

The design for above linked code is given at tinypic.com/view.php?pic=xnaqlt&s=3

I am confused by "super.callTrailer();" in the decorator classes Header1, Header2, Footer1 and Footer2, all derived from TicketDecorator.

Shouldn't it be just "callTrailer();" ? As each decorator object would have its own reference to the next decorator due to the line "private Component myTrailer;".

Note: I am not very well versed in Java and a beginner in Design Patterns.

Comment: Have you looked at http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html ?

Comment: Thanks, I have gone through it and that is what was mostly showing up in search; i.e. it is used to access the parent's method in a derived class when the derived class "overrides" the method. Here the derived class in not overriding it!

Answer (score 2):

They will both give you the same result. Since callTrailer() only exists in the parent class then calling callTrailer() by itself will automatically call the callTrailer() of the TicketDecorator. I guess the reason they put super in there is to make it explicit that it is calling the parent's method.

Comment: Thanks.
But.. If a class B is derived from A. And A has a method x(). B doesn't define (override) x(). So now B also a method x() that can access any members of B. Right? I mean x() is an instance method of B.

Comment: @Imran - if there is no override then If you call x() on B it will call the one on A.

Comment: ok. lets say x() modifies a private member "pv". And as u say x() called is the one in A. Which "pv" is modified? The "pv" in A or the "pv" in B?

Comment: You cannot have a pv in B with the same name. It would modify the one in A.

Comment: And if A is an abstract class, and it has a method y(), that B overrides to have a call super.x(). Now B's "pv" is the only one that x() shall be able to "see"?

Comment: @Imran Lookup the Liskov Substitution principle( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle ). The idea is to have an is-a relationship All the methods in the abstract class should be self contained and apply to any sub-classes. You cannot have a method in a super class that modifies instance variables in a child class.